# Adobe Animate randomly colors images black

Tags: adobe-animate

I was drawing in Adobe Animate. I clicked "select all" so I could move the entire image over a little. I did that, and when I deselected, it randomly colored parts of the drawing black. Why? And it doesn't do this to just one particular color. It seems to be arbitrary which parts it changes to black. Anyway, does this happen to anybody else? Does anybody know if is this a glitch in the latest release of Animate? Does anybody have any ideas? Google is coming up dry.